# "Undefined symbol: _swift_stdlib_isStackAllocationSafe" error after update the Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have a project developed in React native. When I first started working on the project, I was getting the following error. I solved this problem a long time ago. Today Xcode version was updated from 14.2 to 14.3 and this error started popping up again. I think my change was reset. It's gone in the new simulators I've previously installed. But I don't remember what I'm doing now and the solutions I found don't work. I think the solution I need to do should not be a change that will appear under the "source control" in vscode. Because if it were, the problem would make a change and I would be able to see it in the "source control". Can you help me with this?

Macbook pro-2020 i5
"react-native": "0.67.5"

[image]

Comment: Have you solve/fix this error?

Comment: I downgraded back to XCode 14.2 for now, and it all worked

Comment: I was able to run, but I can't archive. But this https://github.com/adaptyteam/AdaptySDK-React-Native/issues/20 has helped me. Just changed the Lib search path.

Comment: any better solution in 2024?

Answer (score 0):

in my case

ios 11, xcode 14.2 build success.
ios 11, xcode 14.3 failed

```
# use_frameworks! // need to comment
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
```

need to delete old podfile.lock and pods folder

```
pod install --repo-update
```

thanks [vishu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14130304/vishu)